# More elegant way to show | hide in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to optimize this jQuery code?

```
$('#hde_test').hide();

$('#shw_test').click(function() {
    $('#shw_test').hide();
    $('#hde_test').show();
    $('.class1').show();
});
$('#hde_test').click(function() { 
    $('#shw_test').show();
    $('#hde_test').hide();
    $('.class1').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can shorten it down:

```
$('#shw_test').click(function() {
    $('#hde_test, #shw_test').toggle();
    $('.class1').show();
});
$('#hde_test').click(function() { 
    $('#hde_test, #shw_test').toggle();
    $('.class1').hide();
});
```

Likely, you can shorten it to:

```
$('#shw_test, #hde_test').click(function() {
    $('#hde_test, #shw_test, .class1').toggle();
});
```

Just depends how the initial state of things are.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [.toggle() method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [.toggleClass() method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle the objects visibility. That would let you do something like:

```
$('#show_toggle').click(function() {
    $('.class1').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could refactor that into a "toggle" function:

```
function toggle(show, hide)
{
   $(show).show();
   $(hide).hide();
}

function doStuff(){
  //this will show shw_test and hide hde_test
  toggle('#shw_test', '#hde_test');

}
```

Comment: jQuery has this built in :) `.toggle(true/false)`

Comment: jQuery already has a .toggle function built in.